# foreach listview items from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, listview

I want to use foreach(ListViewItem item in objectListView1.Items) from another thread but I don't know how.

My code:

```
        void createMoviesXML()
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in objectListView1.Invoke(new Action(() => objectListView1.Items)) // I know it's wrong
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(item.SubItems[0].Text, @"&amp;"))
                {
                    item.SubItems[0].Text = Regex.Replace(item.SubItems[0].Text, @"&amp;", "&");
                }
            }
        }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thr1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(createMoviesXML));
            thr1.Start();
}
```

Comment: So many questions.. the first is why are you using Regex to match a basic string?

Comment: I don't know. I think it's best way. I'm going to expand this regex. Surely this will require foreach from another thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the whole loop on the UI thread since you're touching several controls.

```
void createMoviesXML()
{
    objectListView1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        foreach (var item in objectListView1.Items)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }));
}
```